# Write to file help c#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am taking data from a file and counting the Status Codes and writing it to a file. When I run the program it does separate the StatusCode from the other numbers and in the output in visual studio the counts are correct but the file is blank, nothing writes to it. I've researched inline but still cant figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
using (StreamWriter file1 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\GIT\ELF\csharp\examples\EROIRSImport_sln\EROIRSImport\EROIRSImport\List.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i >= dataInputList.Count; i++)
    {
        DataInput di = dataInputList[i];
        file1.WriteLine("EFIN: "+di.getEFIN()+"  StatusCode: "+di.getStatusCode()+"  StatusDate: "+di.getStatusDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do `i <= dataInputList.Count`. Probably not the issue but please use spaces around + when working with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i >= dataInputList.Count; i++)
```

It appears you have your comparison backwards, my friend. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataInputList.Count; i++)
```

I would also remove the `=` because Count is non-zero inclusive and `i` begins at 0

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I knew it would be something simple. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = @"C:\GIT\ELF\csharp\examples\EROIRSImport_sln\EROIRSImport\EROIRSImport\List.txt";
var lines = dataInputList.Select(di => $"EFIN: {di.GetEFIN()}\tStatusCode: {di.getStatusCode()}\tStatusDate: {di.getStatusDate()}");
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```